# How to debug executable (using gdb) that reads another file?

Tags: debugging, g++

I have a small application let's call it program. In general to use this application I need to stream a file into it:

```
./program < file_with_data.txt
```

How do I debug such program using dbg? I don't know how to pass data from file to program when it is controlled by dbg.

Answer (score 1):

Found it:after running:

```
gdb program
```

write

```
run < file_with_data.txt
```